# How to grep following words from string

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, output

How can I grep the nodeport which is the "31000" under the PORT(S) , it can and will change, from the following kubernetes command output:

```
NAME       TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
vault-ui   NodePort   10.96.62.155   <none>        8200:31000/TCP   23m
```

and how can I grep the ip address(in this case 192.168.99.213) but not the port(8443) or the https:// in following output, this output also changes depending on the ip:

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.99.213:8443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.99.213:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

Comment: Please add your efforts in your question as its highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: Whats unclear about it? grep 2 word from 2 outputs? :) @RavinderSingh13

Comment: I haven't said it unclear, I mentioned about efforts, which is encouraged on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kubecmd | awk -F[:] 'NR>1 { split($2,arr,"/");print arr[1]}'
```

For the first scenario, you can use awk as above. Use : as a field separator and then further split the second delimited piece on / into array arr printing the first element this array the

```
kubecmd | sed -En 's/(^.*Kubernetes master.*https:\/\/)(.*)(:.*$)/\2/p'
```

For the second scenario, use sed as above. Split the text into three sections and print the second section

Comment: Hi! First one works, but the second one is also command so i would need "kubecmd | sed", like the first one, that output I posted is the first line of the output and I only need to grep that ip from that string

Comment: Yeah, just pipe the command output through to sed and remove the <<< ....

Comment: there is now more clarification above @Raman Sailopal

Comment: Try it with the ^ removed and so s/(Kubernetes master...

Comment: I removed it and ran: kubectl cluster-info | sed -En 's/(Kubernetes master is running at https:\/\/)(.*)(:.*$)/\2/p' doesnt return anything

Comment: Just tried this one an environment with Kubernetes and it turns out that the kubectl command adds control characters for colours and so I have amended the answer accordingly